# Problems with having an empty cpp for a header using Template methods

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

i know there are already Questions about defining template methods in cpp Files. But this is not my Question, so pleas don't mark my Question as duplicate. My problem is that even an empty cpp files makes problems.
I have a header file with a class vv. This has template methods and "normal" methods. If i have only a header file it compiles without any error. But if i have a cpp file. It throws following error: "> expected" for the line:     "template"
I get this error even the cpp file is completely empty and there is only a #include "headerfile.h"
I don't know where my error is. I'm using c++ Builder 10.2.
The errors are

> line 5 "> expected"
>
> line 11 "Declaration not proberly closed"
>                   line 11 "unexpected }"

Header File

```
Class vv
{
    void func(int i);

    template<typename Function, typename... Args>
    bool functionImpl(Function f, Args&&... args)
    {
        // do something
         return true;
   } 
};
```

Comment: With typo fixed (missing `;`) it compiles live: https://godbolt.org/z/pcrp_h

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't know where my error is

You have a typo here: `return true`. Add a `;` to end the line and it compiles fine.

> If i have only a header file it compiles without any error. But if i
>   have a cpp file. It throws

You don't compile a *header file* -- that is why you only got the error when including it in a *.cpp file* -- it is only source files that are being compiled, together with the included headers of course.

Comment: @StackTourista Can you update the question with current version of code and the full text of compilation error so I could try help you further?

Comment: Downvoter: Please explain. Please. Why this is a bad answer -- so I could actually know what's wrong with it and try to improve. Why is this voting mechanism being used for hostility I have no idea :(

Comment: I'm sorry, that you get an upvote for helping me. I found your answer very helpful.

Comment: @StackTourista can you try another compiler just for verifying this, as several compiler I have tried all compiled without error. Don't know about C++ Builder as I don't have it right now.

Comment: @StackTourista So did this helped you solve your issue?

Comment: Yeah you helped me a lot. I found the error, it was a wrong setting in the Compiler. With your help, i knew the code was correct and that i have to search the error in the compiler. Thanks a lot. Of course i upvotet your answer. Stackoverflow said that i have not yet enough points, so my upvote will not displayed, but counted.

Comment: @StackTourista Good to hear, helping is the purpose.You can still accept the answer, even if cannot upvote. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers